# How to redirect to different site by path?

Tags: .htaccess

I am wandering how to redirect to different site by path in htaccess.

For example, suppose I have two site: `http://aaa.com` and `http://bbb.com`, and a (host like) site as `http://ccc.com` I want the following behavior works: If we input `http://ccc.com/wordpress/` then all staff go to `http://aaa.com/wordpress/` if we input `http://ccc.com/discuz` then all staff go to `http://bbb.com/discuz`.

Can this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)ccc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^wordpress http://aaa.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)ccc\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^discuz http://bbb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Q1. Is this the only .htaccess or do you have another? Q2. Is this the only code in this .htaccess? If you have some other code then please post it in question? Q3. What is location of above .htaccess?

Comment: I just edit the htaccess for `http://ccc.com`, it seems that when I try `http://ccc.com/discuz` I have been bring to `http://aaa.com/discuz` while for `http://ccc.com/wordpress` it go to search  `http://aaa.com/`  with content `wordpress`.

Comment: Your comment is not clear. As per your question `http://ccc.com/wordpress/` should be redirected to `http://aaa.com/wordpress/` and that is what this rule is already doing. If your scenario is something else then explain it clearly in your question.